# Zend Framework 3, Filter Factory is being passed a container that doesn't have access to configured services

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

Just in the process of migrating from ZF2 to ZF3, and was trying to bring HTMLPurifier on board as filter.

The article here describes how to add filters to the FilterPluginManager
https://zendframework.github.io/zend-filter/writing-filters/

I thought I'd done the necessary:
https://github.com/Saeven/Purifier/blob/master/src/Soflomo/Purifier/Module.php

When attempting to use the filter, the factory is invoked as is expected:
https://github.com/Saeven/Purifier/blob/master/src/Soflomo/Purifier/Factory/Filter/PurifierFilterFactory.php#L14

But the factory dies when it tries to ->get('HTMLPurifierEngine') with this error:

> Uncaught Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Unable to resolve service "HTMLPurifierEngine" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration? in /Users/Saeven/Documents/Circlical/code/Cloudshare/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:675

The funny thing, is that this service is certainly defined, here:
https://github.com/Saeven/Purifier/blob/master/config/module.config.php#L20

I must be missing something obvious.  Maybe staring at it too long...

Do you know how to configure the module to avoid this error?  Why is the service not visible to the container?

Thanks!

Comment: Please put main part of your codes here, it's easier to read. More, external links could be broken...

Comment: I've found the solution, it was an obscure combination of SM changes that now make sense.  I'll post the solution later on.

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer, maybe it will help other people in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have configuration caching enabled? It could cause such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In configuration files, filters have their own entry `input_filters`, and not in `service_manager` key:

```
'input_filters' => array(
    'factories' => [
        'HTMLPurifierEngine' => HtmlPurifierFactory::class,
    ],
),
```

Comment: This was the name of a service that the filter needed, not the filter itself.

Answer (score 0):

In ZF3 there have been some changes as to how and which classmaps are used.

The obvious thing i have always been missing: have you generated the classmaps?

Try

```
$ php composer.phar dump-autoload -o
```

in your Application's root directory.